# How to escape one category from select in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to show all categories in my select, except the one called "Landing".

**My code**

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all(order: :name), :id, :name %>
```

How can I escape "Landing" from the collection?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't put database lookups in your view code. Gather the information in your controller and store it in a variable, then access the variable in the view. That helps the page load and makes the site seem more responsive.

Answer (score 3):

Given you are using rails 4, you can use [`not`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#not-conditions) :

```
Category.where.not( name: 'Landing' )
```

You code becomes :

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.where.not( name: 'Landing' ).order( :name ), :id, :name %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of selecting `all`:

```
Category.all(order: :name)
```

You can limit the results with `where`:

**Rails 4**

```
Category.where.not(name: 'Landing').order(:name)
```

**Rails 3**

```
Category.where("name != 'Landing").order(:name)
```

Comment: Thanks again! Nice stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [arel](/questions/tagged/arel) for `Rails` 3 and 4, or [`fake_arel` gem](https://github.com/gammons/fake_arel) for `Rails` 2:

```
Collection.where(Collection.arel_table[:name].not_eq('Landing')).order(:name)
```